# Connected to WireGuard but don't have access to internet

Tags: networking, server, vpn, wireguard

I try to install WireGuard on my **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** server with this config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 64129
PrivateKey = xxxxx

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;


[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxx
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
```

then, in my Windows OS trying to use WireGuard application as client with this config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxxxx
Address = 10.66.66.2/32, fd42:42:42::2/128

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxx
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = xx.xx.xx.xx:64129
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Also from my client terminal I checked ping of `10.66.66.1` and `8.8.8.8` and also `4.2.2.4` and get the correct response.

This happens when I write `wg` to terminal of server:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: xxxxxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 64129

peer: xxxxxx
  endpoint: xx.xx.xx.xx:56698
  allowed ips: 10.66.66.2/32, fd42:42:42::2/128
  latest handshake: 9 minutes, 23 seconds ago
  transfer: 33.54 KiB received, 13.87 KiB sent
```

I changed `ip_forward` to one:

```
ssh@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Here is my `ufw status`:

```
ssh@ubuntu:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
64129/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
64129/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Anywhere on eth0           ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on wg0
Anywhere on wg0            ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on eth0
Anywhere (v6) on eth0      ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on wg0
Anywhere (v6) on wg0       ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on eth0
```

But, still I can't open any URL in my browser.

and this is `ip a` result :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:0c:b8:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xx.xx.xx.xx/32 brd xx.xx.xx.xx scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxx::xx:xx:xx:xxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.66.66.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd42:42:42::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add `ip a` output ___on your server___.

Comment: I added my `ip a` result

Comment: You don't seem to have "global" IPv6 on your server. So, you should delete any IPv6 related stuff from your configuration.

Comment: It worked but randomly gonna be disconnected. I couldn't understand why this happened. I accepted your answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the `Address` line in the Client (Windows) configuration like this:

```
Address = 10.66.66.2/24, fd42:42:42::2/64
```

Also, to use *IPv6 forwarding*, you should set `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding` to `1`. To make all the forwarding settings persistent, use the command:

```
$ sudo -i
# echo -e 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1\nnet.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1' >>/etc/sysctl.d/10-wireguard.conf
```

Since the `iptables` and `ip6tables` command may be lengthy, I use the following script (named `/etc/wireguard/helper/add-rem_nat_routing.sh` in my case) for `PostUp` and `PostDown`:

***Important: Please enter correct IPv6 subnet addresses below, or delete IPv6-related stuff:***

```
#!/bin/bash
OPT="$1"
case "$OPT" in
  "-I" )
    OPT2="1"
    ;;
  "-D" )
    OPT2=""
    ;;
  * )
    echo "Unknown option: $OPT" >&2
    exit 2
    ;;
esac
IPT="/usr/sbin/iptables"
IPT6="/usr/sbin/ip6tables"
IN_FACE="eth0"          ## NIC connected to the internet
WG_FACE="$2"            ## WG NIC
SUB_NET="10.66.66.0/24" ## WG IPv4 sub/net aka CIDR
WG_PORT="64129"         ## WG udp port
SUB_NET_6="fd42:42:42::/112" ## WG IPv6 sub/net CORRECT THIS!!!
### IPv4 ###
$IPT -t nat $OPT POSTROUTING $OPT2 -s $SUB_NET -o $IN_FACE -j MASQUERADE
$IPT $OPT INPUT   $OPT2 -i $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT $OPT FORWARD $OPT2 -i $IN_FACE -o $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT $OPT FORWARD $OPT2 -i $WG_FACE -o $IN_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT $OPT INPUT   $OPT2 -i $IN_FACE -p udp --dport $WG_PORT -j ACCEPT
### IPv6 (comment these if you DO NOT have IPv6) ###
$IPT6 -t nat $OPT POSTROUTING $OPT2 -s $SUB_NET_6 -o $IN_FACE -j MASQUERADE
$IPT6 $OPT INPUT   $OPT2 -i $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 $OPT FORWARD $OPT2 -i $IN_FACE -o $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 $OPT FORWARD $OPT2 -i $WG_FACE -o $IN_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 $OPT INPUT   $OPT2 -i $IN_FACE -p udp --dport $WG_PORT -j ACCEPT
```

And call it like this in the server configuration:

```
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/helper/add-rem_nat_routing.sh -I "%i"
PostDown = /etc/wireguard/helper/add-rem_nat_routing.sh -D "%i"
```

Note: You should run `systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0` after changing server configuration.

Please, test the following on the server:

```
$ traceroute 1.1.1.1
```

and the following on the client (after WireGuard connection):

```
C:\> tracert 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed Address to `10.66.66.2/24, fd42:42:42::2/64` in Client configuration and `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding ` is 1 , and its all same and whenever change server configuration of client to `10.66.66.2/24, fd42:42:42::2/64`  also `wg` command show me like this `allowed ips: 10.66.66.0/24, fd42:42:42::/64`